# "org.json.JSONObject" cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android

When I am trying to access the Content of this below JSON , I am getting the Exception.

This is My JSON Value:

```
{"listDev":{"description":"D4684","deviceID":"d2","uniqueID":"0014018682"}}
```

This is my code to get the Content in "listDev"

```
JSONObject object = ApplicationContext.getHttpService().readAsJson(content);
JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("listDev");
```

So, what to do to get the Contents like decription, imei...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: array has [] object {} so this is JSON OBJECT

Answer (score 0):

listDev is a `JSONObject` not a `JSONArray`:

change

```
JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("listDev");
```

to

```
JSONObject array = object.getJSONObject("listDev");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String json = {"listDev":{"description":"D4684","deviceID":"d2","uniqueID":"0014018682"}};
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
JSONObject array = object.getJSONArray("listDev");
```